# Intermittent NullReferenceException on ASP.Net WebAPI application running on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

We are having some intermittent issues on one of our servers where the api has intermittent 500s with the following error and then it keeps happening after some time until we restart the iis or the server. This does not happen on local IIS.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetStepArray(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent) +30
   System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetEventCount(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent) +8
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +1243
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +493
```

This happens on IIS 7.5 and the application is built using .net 4.5. Sometimes it runs ok for 2000 requests and then starts throwing 500s for every other few requests. 
I wondered if this was an issue with the order or http modules but I don't know why it only happens sometimes.

Any idea how to troubleshoot or fix this?

Comment: Sounds like are resource leak, are you disposing all used resources?

Comment: well it works on other servers. same code. I have asked for a new server build (this is UAT environment) but I would like to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Hard to guess without any code to look at. Have you figured out which variable is null and what line of code is supposed to be setting it? That would be a good start.

Comment: @JohnWu I am not sure which line or variable as it's .net internal libraries. I wonder if this is related to any configurations on IIS as it is working fine on other servers.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code, there is an object null check which isn't properly handled.

Comment: it's not the code as it works on other environments. We created a new server and it worked. No change.